# What does having two file extensions do in Rails (i.e.: .css.scss)?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I am working in Ruby on Rails and I'm generating controllers and views through (`rails g controller`). It is giving me a `.css.scss` file and a `js.coffee` file.  I'm assuming this is a valid form of a file extension, considering it was generated through Rails.

If a file has two file extensions, how does the program that interprets code knows which one to use?

i.e.:

`somefile.css.scss` --> CSS or SCSS?

and

`somefile.js.coffee` --> CoffeeScript or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are pre-processors. so `index.html` is plain html. `index.html.erb` is html with embedded ruby enabled. `index.js.coffee` is a javascript file that you can write as coffeescript. `index.js.coffee.erb` is a javascript file you can write in coffeescript and embed ruby in (mind you please try to avoid js with erb)

read more here: https://learn.co/lessons/asset-preprocessors-in-rails

the functional reason to use this, as described in the post above, is to be able to write in one language, which converts into another, or to embed functionality that otherwise wouldn't be available. (in a nutshell)

Comment: So the article says that it converts them from one file to another, is this only valid in Rails or is it valid even without a Rails application?

Comment: its a rails asset pipeline thing. ruby doesnt have this by default.

Answer (score 2):

Only the last file extension will be used:

`somefile.css.scss` will be a SASS file.

`somefile.coffee.js` will be a JavaScript file.

I'm assuming the Rails application is converting from CSS to SASS (odd, usually the other way around) and from CoffeeScript to JavaScript, and that's why it's naming the files like that.

Comment: Is there a functional reason for why you would ever use this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "functional reason." In this case it is used as a reminder of what format the previous file was. Another common usage is to specify a minimized file such as `somefile.min.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Always the latest extension assumed as file extension.